# Database architecture for asp.net mvc websites builder system

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server, database-design

I want to create the design of a SQL database that will hold the data entered from a dynamic created websites (something like http://www.wufoo.com).
Users of the system will create forms by dragging controls into the form and then they will use the created forms to build a website by including the forms in some pages.
What would be the options that I have when I create the architecture of the database.

Comment: are you looking for Database Architecture? Would you explain more? Or you are looking for Database Design (like ERD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not know what you will get in your DB, how the object will look like; I would suggest using NoSql.

Otherwise you need to create some very abstract table, let's say Form, and then make in inheritable by other tables (ye, you can do that in [EF](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx))

Comment: What is the benefits of using NoSql?

Comment: You don't know the structure of the database, so NoSql will let you store your objects as JSons. 

On a separate note, you may approve the answer/vote  up if you find it useful.

Comment: I did because I think that NoSQL the best choice for me, thanks